# «Поезда ждут рельсы». Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Поезда ждут рельсы». Верно ли построено предложение?

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически правильно, стилистика хромает, ибо непонятно сходу, кто кого ждет и зачем.

Ну поскольку комментарии убраны...

А в них было вполне содержательное объяснение, воспроизведу здесь. 
Речь идет о Крымском мосте и поездах, которые "ждут рельсы", которые должны появиться осенью. К ж/д сленгу, таким образом, отношения не имеет.
Однако при грамматической правильности фразы она вызывает затруднения в понимании, если не знать сути дела.

@АртёмЛуговой

> @behemothus: а не может быть так: пОезда ждут рельсы? Поезда в ед. ч.
>   р. п.

Если оторваться от исторического контекста, то может, конечно, я и написал, что фраза неоднозначна.  ))) Но, правда, в таком случае стилистика предписывает иметь подлежащее на первом месте.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93045/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus------).

Answer (score 0):

Это, скорее всего, железнодорожный сленг. Ждут, когда рельсы освободятся для их (поездов) проезда. Может, там ремонтники закопошились - окончательно график сбивают.

«Поезда ждут рельсы» звучит как диспетчерская команда. (Понятная и непосвящённому.)

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Диспетчер про "рельсы" ничего не знает. У них только "путь". Это совсем не про то. Очередной приступ крымской мостостроительной лихорадки, судя по всему.